# How do I translate the "All categories" text in the search field?

Tags: magento2, porto-theme

I have a Magento 2 setup with a danish language package installed and porto theme.
But the search fields text "All categories" is not translated:

[image: 2]

I tried to add a i18n folder in my theme. Both in the the root "porto_child" and in the Magento_Search.

[image]

The content of da_dk.csv:

```
"All categories", "Alle kategorier"
```

But I can't get it to translate.

I saw this post [How to properly transalte All Categories to another language?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290270/how-to-properly-transalte-all-categories-to-another-language)
But I don't have a vendor/mageplaza folder, though the danish translation is from Mageplaze. I don't know where that translation lives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find below file in your module

> Mageplaza\Search\Helper\Data.php

and find function

```
getCategoryTree()
```

[image]

and use here `All Categories` word with standard magento way..

Comment: Awesome thanks!.. Whats the best way to override this?

Comment: @JonasBorneland please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45429776/10748606

Comment: Thanks!! I will make an helper override